# odoo 14: how i can add additional fields in SignUp like address etc

Tags: python, odoo

i want to add some additional fields in odoo signup form/view like address and also wants to know where it is saving signup data (table) so i can reference / track to it for user related activities. please guide the steps i have to done to achieve this.
regards

Comment: you're asking to learn odoo from scratch 

Comment: i don't know about where odoo store signup data (the model / table) and what is its xml part (view) & controllers etc. how it can be done if i don't know about the source?

Comment: ok, i searched and found i have to inherit res.uers to add required fields, override controller class AuthSignupHome(AuthSignupHome) and inherit and add in xml template  but i can only inherit model res.uers and add fields, but don't know how to's about controller and xml template parts, please help for these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to inherit [auth_signup.fields](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/auth_signup/views/auth_signup_login_templates.xml#L12) template to add the field to the sign-up page. The following code add the `street` to the signup fields.

```
<odoo>
    <template id="signup_fields" inherit_id="auth_signup.fields" name="Auth Signup street form field">
        <xpath expr="//div[last()]" position="after">
            <div class="form-group field-login">
                <label for="street">Street</label>
                <input type="text" name="street" id="street" class="form-control form-control-sm"/>
            </div>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

When you click on the `submit` button, the [web_auth_signup](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/auth_signup/controllers/main.py#L29) controller method will be called. The first thing the controller will do is call [do_signup](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/auth_signup/controllers/main.py#L119) to prepare values and call the [signup](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/auth_signup/models/res_users.py#L56) method of the `res.users` to write values to the database.

To save the `street` field value, you can override the [_signup_with_values](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/auth_signup/controllers/main.py#L133) method:

```py
from odoo.addons.auth_signup.controllers.main import AuthSignupHome


class AuthSignupStreet(AuthSignupHome):
    def _signup_with_values(self, token, values):
        context = self.get_auth_signup_qcontext()
        values.update({'street': context.get('street')})
        super(AuthSignupStreet, self)._signup_with_values(token, values)
```

Comment: thanks @Kenly , will apply and check then give feedback here. just one more related thing, if i have more than 1 fields to add, i have to copy complete line values.update to make for another field and change the name of fields here? or copy this line from {'street': till }  ... sorry, but i have very little knowledge, not yet touched controllers to create or inherit. regards

Comment: You need to add a div block for each field then update the values like following: `values.update({'field1': context.get('field1'), 'field2': context.get('field2'), ...})`.

Comment: in controller file, i am using single field at the moment for test, but it is showing an error on line from odoo.addons.auth_signup.controllers.main import AuthSignupHome,  the error is " Cannot find reference 'auth_signup' in __init__.py "  " Unresolved reference 'AuthSignupHome'  " ... i think i am missing something here.

Comment: is this needs to add in auth_signup own controllers file main.py? i am adding in my own module's controller.

Comment: Yes of course. Also add the module to the manifest `depends` entry.

Comment: when modify addons/auth_signup/controllers/main.py to add this code, it shows various errors for existing ones like: cannot find reference 'auth_signup' in __init__.py

Comment: You said that you added your own module? If you want to modify the original controller, you have just to add your field to the set `('login', 'name', 'password', 'field1', ...)`.

Comment: hi @Kenly i have added as Answer what have done, but still not getting success.

Answer (score 1):

please check following, file names with path, in models.py file inherit res.users and add 2 fields, in main.py file added 'contact_no', 'address' and in template.xml file as per your code, added 2 fields but still i failed to have these on signup form.

custom_addons/tests/models/models.py:

```
class ResUsersExt(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.users'

    contact_no = fields.Char(string='Contact No.', required=True)
    address = fields.Char(string='Address', required=True)
```

addons/auth_signup/controllers/main.py:

```
def do_signup(self, qcontext):
    """ Shared helper that creates a res.partner out of a token """
    values = {key: qcontext.get(key) for key in ('login', 'name', 'password', 'contact_no', 'address')}
    if not values:
        raise UserError(_("The form was not properly filled in."))
    if values.get('password') != qcontext.get('confirm_password'):
        raise UserError(_("Passwords do not match; please retype them."))
    supported_lang_codes = [code for code, _ in request.env['res.lang'].get_installed()]
    lang = request.context.get('lang', '').split('_')[0]
    if lang in supported_lang_codes:
        values['lang'] = lang
    self._signup_with_values(qcontext.get('token'), values)
    request.env.cr.commit()
```

custom_addons/tests/views/template.xml:

```
<template id="signup_fields" inherit_id="auth_signup.fields" name="Auth Signup Ext form fields">
    <xpath expr="//div[last()]" position="after">
        <div class="form-group field-contact_no">
            <label for="contact_no">Contact No.</label>
            <input type="text" name="contact_no" id="contact_no" class="form-control form-control-sm"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group field-address">
            <label for="address">Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="form-control form-control-sm"/>
        </div>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Comment: this code worked prefectly, all credits goes to @Kenly, it was my fault, just added controllers in "__init__.py" file on module's main path " from . import controllers " and it works as needed. very grateful to Kenly for help.